# I just learned you can have nested classes in C#, what is the point of this?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are reasons why one would want to use nested classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300051/what-are-reasons-why-one-would-want-to-use-nested-classes)

I found some example code online for something unrelated, and it had nested classes. I thought this was a mistake, and the outer one should have been Namespace, but the code compiled and worked fine.

What are nested classes used for? Is this a good programming practice?

Comment: And a couple of more duplicates: [When should I create a nested class? Does it make instantiation of the outer class consume more resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361830/when-should-i-create-a-nested-class-does-it-make-instantiation-of-the-outer-clas) | [Where and how to use nested classes ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143670/where-and-how-to-use-nested-classes) | [Why/when should you use nested classes in .net? Or shouldn't you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872/why-when-should-you-use-nested-classes-in-net-or-shouldnt-you)

Comment: Typed my question, scrolled through the list of suggestions... nothing...d'oh

Answer (score 1):

- So that you don't litter a namespace with classes. Inner, nested classes are visible only to the parent class, or when typing ParentClass.*, rather than spamming the namespace with classes that are only ever used once by one single class
- It allows you to logically group all elements of a class within a single file (including subclasses)
- More maintainable. It's easier to read small classes in its parent class rather than having to open another file to read a few lines

Comment: you can also have multiple (public, private, internal) classes within a single file.

Comment: With regard to readability of smaller classes, quite often using partial classes will resolve that particular problem.

Comment: @Jamie, that's true. But with smaller classes, I find that smaller classes nested in larger ones makes it easier to refer to when revising code.